# How do I clear what I typed into the prompt?

Tags: bash, terminal

I type a really, really long command into bash. Whoops, it was the wrong command.
As of now, this means that I go through two hells:

1. Realizing my command was useless.
2. Having to clear my shell by holding down <kbd>Backspace</kbd> until the prompt is clear.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Control + A` then `Control + K`. The first moves your cursor to the beginning of the line, the second clears the line after the cursor.

A messier way to do this is hit enter and then hit `Control + C`. Credit to @billc.cn

If you want to clear the whole prompt, use `Control + L`.

Comment: Ctrl + C is quicker in some cases, although quite ugly :P

Comment: I didn't think that it was relevant. I thought he wanted to clear the line, not kill a running program.

Comment: Just type something in to `bash` and press Ctrl-C and see what you get.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Yeah that works also.

Comment: Aye, those darned emacs keybindings.

Comment: Ctrl-L clears the screen, but retains what you've typed in.

Comment: So that does the opposite of what he wants.

Answer (score 28):

Ctrl-U clears the command input you've typed, up to the current cursor position.  So if you're using it just after you've typed the command, but haven't moved the cursor back, it'll clear everything you've typed.

Comment: Actually, it "Clears the line before the cursor position. If you are at the end of the line, clears the entire line." Which is close, but not totally accurate all the time. It is the opposite of Ctrl + K

Comment: Good point.  In the situation posed in the question, though, the cursor is probably at the end of the line, so it should work for this purpose.

I've fixed the answer to clarify this.

Comment: Hence my upvote.

Comment: @Alger for me it is always clearing everything regardless of of where the cursor is moved back or not. `echo $0`  returns `/bin/csh`.

Comment: +1 because this works in both mysql shell and bash shell :D